# What is the behaviour when accessing Google Drive from a shared Google Colab notebook?

Tags: google-colaboratory

This may be terribly obvious, but I wanted to make sure.

Put simply, say, I have a Google Colab notebook that is shared with another person (either I share it with them or they share it with me). In this notebook, I mount and allow access to my Drive. Naturally, I can access all of the files on the Drive from the notebook.

Now, what is the behavior of the notebook at the other end? Does the call to mounting the drive simply use the other person's Drive (and potentially fail to locate a file if it is not present on their Drive) or does it retain the mounting of my own Drive?

Essentially, can the other person view/access files and folders that were not shared with them via Drive in a Google Colab notebook? I doubt that's the case, but I am not sure. Feel free to elaborate on the inner workings.

I have not yet tried it myself. I figured I would make sure before proceeding with sharing the notebook.